# Creating an index of wildcard DNS names

Tags: postgresql, index, dns

I want to have a table column which will be filled with wildcard-type DNS entries, like

```
*.example.org
*.popularisp.net
```

such that I can make fast queries against actual reverse DNS hostnames, matching `foobar.example.org` to the first one above and `12-34-56-78.routers.popularisp.net` to the second, for instance.

What is the best way to achieve this in a PostgreSQL index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation I found the best way to go was to just index the wildcard forms of names, generate wildcards in the application, and do queries like

```
SELECT * 
FROM domain 
WHERE hostname IN ('12-34-56-78.routers.popularisp.net', '*.routers.popularisp.net', '*.popularisp.net', '*.net')
```

since the numbers of levels of hierarchy are low.

Answer (score 1):

as dns domains are parsed from the end, it's useful to also store them that way - e.g:
For `bar.foo.co.uk` you'll keep `uk.co.foo.Bar`.

It makes both indexing and prefix searches simple and fast. 
In the example above you'll search for `uk.co.foo.%` - a simple search for regular index.

Note: it's the same way many directory (ldap,dns, etc. ) searches work.

Comment: So something like `SELECT […] FROM domains WHERE '12-34-56-78.routers.popularisp.net' LIKE hostname` (assuming `domains` is the table and `hostname` is the column I’m trying to create)?

Comment: Hi, you'll need to reverse the query string as well, so:  `where 'net.popularisp.routers.12-34-56-78' like hostname` (not the best example as this has no wildcard...)

Comment: Okay, it doesn't work because `pattern LIKE col_name` doesn't work with indexes apparently …

Comment: Take a look at `pg_trgm` and `gist` indexes - they give more flexibility to work with patterns...